# restar una cantidad de 5 en 5

Tags: c++, codeblocks

gente sera que me puedan ayudar en este problema quiero hacer un programita basico que pueda restar 100 de 5 en 5, donde se vea dicha resta en plan

este es mi codigo

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero = 100;
    
    int acumulador=0;
    
    bool iniciar = true;
    

    
    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
     
     acumulador -= numero - 5;
     
     if(acumulador == 0){
         
         std::cout << acumulador << std::endl;
         
     }
     

    }


    return 0;
}
```

me dicen que me falta ,gracias

**solo quiero hacer un acumulador que me reste la cantidad de 100 en 5 en 5 y mostrar todo ese desgloce**

la salida que quiero que tenga es la resta hasta 0

```
95 
90
85
80
etc hasta 0
```

Comment: esta línea: `acumulador -= numero - 5;`?

Comment: solo quiero hacer un acumulador que me reste de 5 en 5 una cantidad y me muestre en pantalla toda esa  resta

Comment: Si, mas o menos se pudo entender que necesitas (a pesar de la semántica). No  recuerdo mucho de c pero ahí veo que solo haces un print cuando acumulador es 0 (cero). Para mostrar el resultado esperado deberías hacer un print en cada iteración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un `for` puedes colocar otro inicial distinto a cero, y otra forma "incremental" además del `i++`, por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero = 100;
    
    for (int i=numero; i>=0; i=i-5){
       std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Aquí el `for` lo iniciamos en "numero" (es decir 100), le decirnos que siga iterando mientras `i` sea mayor o igual a cero, y que en cada iteración a `i` se le reste 5. Es decir `i` será: 100, 95, 90, 85, etc

Comment: o waw, muchas gracias, la verdad andaba algo apurada porque es para una tarea, pero obviamente uno lo explica mucho más simple para no entrar en explicaciones innecesarias, pero muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho

Comment: @EstherPorta Me alegro te haya servido, suerte con la tarea!!

Comment: Creo que **i >= o;** va a imprimir bla bla.. **-5**, mas bien usa **i > 0;**.

Comment: @MarcePuente Imprime del 100 al 0, con `i>0` imprimiría del 100 al 5

Comment: @Yussef, como siempre, el maestro tiene razón!! jaja.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int minuendo=100;
    int sustraendo=5;
    
    while (minuendo != 0) {
        minuendo = minuendo - sustraendo;
        cout << minuendo << endl;
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hola nunca he programado en c++ pero siguiendo la lógica de programación doy esta posible solución:
(los 3 primeros comentarios explican lo que hace cada parte del ciclo `for` que se encuentra separado por punto y coma `;`)

```
int main()
{
    // numero empieza en 100;
    // el ciclo seguirá mientras numero sea mayor o igual a 0
    // numero irá disminuyendo de 5 en 5

    for (int numero=100; numero>=0; numero-=5){

    // aquí colocas lo que quieras hacer con el numero en cada iteración

    }


    return 0;
}
```

espero y te sea de ayuda, saludos!